# currently can't install anything with npm code ERESOLVE

Tags: npm, npm-install, sveltekit

currently, everytime I want to install an NPM package, I get this error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit@0.10.7
npm ERR! Found: @sveltejs/kit@2.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@sveltejs/kit
npm ERR!   peer @sveltejs/kit@"^2.0.0" from @sveltejs/adapter-auto@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@sveltejs/adapter-auto
npm ERR!     dev @sveltejs/adapter-auto@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   dev @sveltejs/kit@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @sveltejs/kit@"^1.15.4" from @supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit@0.10.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit
npm ERR!   @supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit@"^0.10.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sveltejs/kit@1.30.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@sveltejs/kit
npm ERR!   peer @sveltejs/kit@"^1.15.4" from @supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit@0.10.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit
npm ERR!     @supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit@"^0.10.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/nevillebrem/.npm/_logs/2023-12-16T13_21_30_675Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/nevillebrem/.npm/_logs/2023-12-16T13_21_30_675Z-debug-0.log
```

this would be my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wolffebricks-v3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
    "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "test:integration": "playwright test",
    "test:unit": "vitest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
    "@skeletonlabs/skeleton": "2.6.0",
    "@skeletonlabs/tw-plugin": "0.3.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "0.5.10",
    "@types/node": "20.10.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.30.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.32",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte": "^4.2.7",
    "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-tailwind-purgecss": "0.1.4",
    "vitest": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@floating-ui/dom": "1.5.3",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit": "^0.10.7",
    "@supabase/ssr": "^0.0.10",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.0",
    "stripe": "^14.9.0"
  }
}
```

The error message sometimes is different with different packages. because of that I can't deploy to Netlify and generally can't install any packages or uninstall any packages. what is wrong? how can I solve that??

Answer (score 0):

You are using SvelteKit 2, which has only been out for a few days, this leads to conflicts in your other dependencies which expect version 1.

> Conflicting peer dependency: @sveltejs/kit@1.30.3

You can either:

- Not use dependencies like `@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit` that expect v1
- Go back to SvelteKit 1 until all dependencies have caught up and have versions compatible with SvelteKit 2
- Try you luck with `--force`, though this may break depending on how the dependency uses SvelteKit

Comment: Yeah the problem is, I want to deploy to Netlify,  but can't since I am always getting this error...